# AWS Lambda can't find my module

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am trying to do a simple require of my own lib in AWS Lambda, but it can't find it. What am I missing?

```
var a = require('./lib/a');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    callback(null, 'Testing');

}
```

Yeah, this works when testing it locally, but not when zipped and deployed. I am zipping just the file, not the directory and removing the require makes it work.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module './lib/a'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:1:77)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)"
  ]
}
```

Directory structure:
index.js
lib/a.js

Comment: "I am zipping just the file, not the directory". If you aren't including the `./lib` directory in the zip file then how can you expect Lambda to find the module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am zipping just the file

Try to download your package from the AWS Lambda console. You'll receive a zip file and try to extract that on your local machine. Can you see the `lib` folder with `a.js` inside it?

Chances are, the zip file that you uploaded probably missed the `lib` directory.

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot. No it just wasn't there, I am adapting an old build script for Amazon and the lib directory wasn't added to the zip-file. Thanks.